# Bot authentication by providing app id and password from a json file

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to authenticate my bot by providing the bot's app id and password from a json file instead of getting the details from web.config file. I tried using connectorclient class from bot connector sdk by passing the details as an argument to it.

I am getting "AADSTS7000216: 'client_assertion', 'client_secret' or 'request' is required for the 'client_credentials' grant type." error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far and provide a minimum sample? Are you using v3 or v4 Bot Framework?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about bot v3?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

The current way to store a bot's app ID and password is already in a JSON file known as a bot file. In Bot Builder V4, reading the bot file is as easy as:

```
botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath, botFileSecret);
```

If you want to use something like a bot file in V3 and you want to leave the credentials out of Web.config, you can create your own credential provider. You might make something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace NetBot.Credentials
{
    public class BotFileCredentialProvider : SimpleCredentialProvider
    {
        private const string BotFile = "NetBot.bot";

        public BotFileCredentialProvider()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().First(resource => resource.Contains(BotFile));

            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                dynamic botConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());
                IEnumerable<dynamic> services = botConfig.services;
                dynamic endpoint = services.FirstOrDefault(service => service.type == "endpoint");

                if (endpoint != null)
                {
                    AppId = endpoint.appId;
                    Password = endpoint.appPassword;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This of course depends on my bot file "NetBot.bot" being an embedded resource. You'll want to modify this if your JSON is formatted differently from a bot file. To use this credential provider, you'll need to modify the `BotAuthentication` attribute on your messages controller:

```
[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType = typeof(BotFileCredentialProvider))]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
```

This of course only uses your JSON credentials to authenticate incoming messages. The Bot Builder SDK will still look for credentials in your Web.config to authenticate outgoing messages. If you want to use your JSON credentials to send messages, you can get the credentials from the claims identity:

```
var credentials = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).GetCredentialsFromClaims();
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), credentials);
```

This will work for when you construct the connector client yourself, but what if you want to send messages from a dialog context? In your Global.asax.cs file, you can insert the following code to get the SDK's connector client factory to always construct its connector clients using claims, just like how you can do it when you construct a connector client manually:

```
builder.Register(c => ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).GetCredentialsFromClaims())
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```